# Obiee Formula to show TIMESTAMP only hours format

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, obiee

I have the following formula:

```
TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_SECOND, CAST(("Agent Performance Facts"."ACD After Call Work Outbound Time (Seconds)" + "Agent Performance Facts"."Inbound Talk Time (Seconds)" + "Agent Performance Facts"."Inbound Hold Time (Seconds)")  AS INTEGER), TIMESTAMP '1999-01-01 00:00:00')
```

When report created I get time as the following example **1/1/1999  4:08:40 AM** I want it to show like this only **4:08** how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Criteria, edit the column properties and under Data Format, set the format to `HH:mm`. You'll probably have to use a custom date format as this won't be in the list of defaults.